# Use local json file with Cordova/ionic/Angular. Works in browser, but not on device?

Tags: ios, json, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm attempting to use a JSON object living in a `data.json` file to be the dataset for a quick prototype I'm working on. This lives in a `my_project/www/data/` directory. I have an Angular service that goes and grabs the data within this file using `$http`, does some stuff to it, and then it's used throughout my app.

I'm using Cordova and Ionic. When using `ionic serve` on my computer, everything looks perfect in the browser. However, when using `ionic view` (http://view.ionic.io/) and opening the app on my iPad, I see a:

```
{"data":null,"status":0,"config":{"method":"GET","transformRequest":[null],"transformResponse":[null],"url":"../data/items.json","headers":{"Accept":"application/json,test/plain,*/*}},"statusText":""}
```

for a response. I would think that if it were a relative URL issue, that it would also not work in the browser, but that is not the case.

Here's what I'm doing:

config.xml has this line:

```
<access origin="*" subdomains="true"/>
```

My service that preforms the simple request is doing:

```
return $http.get("../data/data.json").then(function (response) {
    return response.data;
});
```

And finally, in my controller, I ask for the service to preform the request:

```
 myService.goGetData().then(onComplete, onError);
```

In my browser, onComplete() is invoked and on the iPad, onError() is invoked.
Any guidance?

Comment: Hey Amy -- what's the error passed to onError?

Comment: Hey Jason! It's just the response object from $http.get -- the object listed above is what onError gets.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On your local developer machine you're actually running a webserver when you run ionic serve. So a path like ../../data.json will work because it is totally valid in the context of the webserver that has complete filesystem access.

If, however, you try to do the same thing on your device, you're probably going to run into an issue because the device has security policies in place that don't allow ajax to traverse up outside of the root.  It is not a dynamic webserver so it can't load files up the tree. Instead you'd use something like the [cordova file plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file) to grab the file contents from the filesystem. If you prefer, you can use [ngCordova](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/file/) to make interacting with the plugin a bit less painful.

I am 99% sure this is what is happening but you can test my theory by pointing your $http call to some dummy .json data hosted on a publicly available server to see if it works. [Here](http://www.reddit.com/r/angularjs.json) is some dummy json data.

Comment: Using $http and JSON data hosted elsewhere works well. I'm going to give the file plugin a try and see if I find success. Do you know if this plugin is the only way to do what I'm attempting?

Comment: I think so, but if I recall, ionic view has support for most of the standard plugins so it should work up on their servers too.

Comment: Could another alternative be to store the data file in a nested location instead of `..` up the tree? So in a data folder sibling to the app file, and call `data/data.json` for example?

Comment: to follow up on what rhodejason, make sure that file is being copied to the device.  An easy way of doing this is to toss the json file in your www folder.

Comment: Could be a path reference problem, I've had problems like this when the scripts get minified and concatenated.

Comment: @rhodesjason, I tried this and no luck. As long as I am trying to access the local file via $http(), it fails. Using the file plugin solved the problem. I was hoping to use $http since long term, the app will be using data on a server of course, but this will do for the temporary prototype. Thanks for your help, all!

Answer (score 6):

Just gonna leave this here because I had the same problem as the original question author. Simply removing any starting slashes from the json file path in the $http.get function solved this problem for me, now loading the json data works both in the browser emulator and on my android device. The root of the $http call url seems to always be the index.html folder no matter where your controller or service is located. So use a path relative from that folder and it should work. like $http.get("data/data.json")

Comment: as @Aether mentioned, check your path & make sure it doesn't start with a "/". Removing the / from the relative path worked for me as well.

Answer (score 2):

So this is an example json file. save it as data.json

```
 [
        {
         "Name" : "Sabba",
         "City" : "London",
          "Country" : "UK"
        },
       {
         "Name" : "Tom",
         "City" : "NY",
         "Country" : "USA"
       }
     ]
```

And this this is what a example controller looks like

```
 var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ionic']);
    app.controller('ExhibitionTabCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope,$http) {
      $http.get("your/path/from/index/data.json")
      .success(function (response) 
      {
       $scope.names = response;
      });
    }]);
```

Then in your template make sure you are you are referencing your controller.

```
  <ion-content class="padding" ng-controller="ExhibitionTabCtrl">
```

You should then be able to use the a expression to get the data

```
{{ names }}
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

I was also looking for this and found this question, since there is no real answer to the problem I kept my search on the Internet and found [this answer](http://forum.ionicframework.com/t/reading-json-file-from-local-for-android-ios/10648/3) at the Ionic Forum from ozexpert:

```
var url = "";
if(ionic.Platform.isAndroid()){
    url = "/android_asset/www/";
}
```

I've used it to load a 3D model and its textures.

Answer (score 0):

update: ionic 2 beta (version date 10 Aug 2016)

You must add prefix to local url like this: prefix + 'your/local/resource'.

prefix by platform:

```
ios = '../www/'
android = '../www/'
browser = ''
```

we can create an urlResolver provider to do this job.

notice: only change url in *.ts code to access local resource, don's do this with remote url or in html code.
Have fun and good luck with beta version.

An Starter Ioner

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to access local resources using $http.get.

If the json file is located in www/js/data.json. You can access using

```
js/data.json
```

Do not use ../js/data.json. Using that only works in the local browser. Use js/data.json will work on both local browser and iOS device for Cordova.